# How to change the login URL

Tags: login

I want to change the login URL per a client request.

so, instead of mysite.com/wp-login.php

or mysite.com/wp-admin

it is this: mysite.com/someotherpagename.php
or mysite.com/someotherpagename

I do not want to use /login. It's too obvious, per the client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Security by obscurity is not security. Changing the login path won't make things safer, just harder to maintain in the future.

Comment: If it stops thousands of bots finding your site and doing a DOS attack it is a level of security.

Answer (score 1):

Open your .htaccess file and add Rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteRule ^myregister/?$ /wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mylogin/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
```

If your wordpress installed in a subdirectory:

```
RewriteRule ^myregister/?$ /subdirectory/wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mylogin/?$ /subdirectory/wp-login.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, It worked but; it just added new access to the login but the original one still there and any hacker can reach to it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easy using [WPS hide login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/) plugin